# Github action build project and create release with project executable

Tags: github-actions

I have a golang project and I want to create an action that builds the project (on ubuntu and windows) and creates a release whenever I create a version tag. I have seen several answers based on actions/create-release but that is now deprecated and not maintained. I'm looking for an alternative.

My approach so far was to build the project, use actions/upload-artifact and then push these artifacts to the release with some notes.

```yaml
name: Build and Create Release

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - v*

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Set up Go
      uses: actions/setup-go@v4
      with:
        go-version: '1.20'

    - name: Build
      run: go build -o main main.go
    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
      with:
```

If there is a solution that provides automated semantic versioning based on git commits, I would be interested in that too. If my approach of creating manual tags is seen as bad practice.

Comment: Did you try using [this action](https://github.com/ncipollo/release-action) instead of the deprecated one, to create the release?

Comment: @GuiFalourd Oh, I'm new to github actions and didn't know this existed. Thank you, I'll try using that.

Comment: The alternative actions are already listed under ["Maintained Actions"](https://github.com/actions/create-release?tab=readme-ov-file#github-action---releases-api).